# Custom View is only displayed on the upper left corner

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-custom-view

what I want to do is to add a custom view to my activity and freely drag and drop it wherever I want to. I create a new class "Square". When I construct a new Square it is displayed in the upper left Corner of the Display. When I set X and Y coordinates it disappears. If I set X and Y to 30 I see that the Square is displayed partiatelly. So it seems that my view is only displayed in a small Frame on the top Left of the Display.
Please help me to move my custom view oder the Display. Thanks!

MainActivity:

```
private Button btnNewSquare;
private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
private Square[] square = new Square[10];
int squareId = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnNewSquare = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout);

    btnNewSquare.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v == btnNewSquare) {
        squareId++;
        square[squareId] = new Square(this);
        square[squareId].setX(30);
                    square[squareId].setY(30);
        square[squareId].setOnTouchListener(square[squareId]);
        relativeLayout.addView(square[squareId]);
        relativeLayout.invalidate();
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Square" + squareId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();           
        square[squareId].invalidate();          
    }
}
```

Square

```
private int squareWidth = 100;
private Paint paint;

public Square(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initSquare();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Square(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initSquare();
}

private final void initSquare() {
    paint = new Paint();
}   

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

   setMeasuredDimension(squareWidth, squareWidth);
}   

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {    
    //super.onDraw(canvas);
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    canvas.drawRect(getX(), getY(), getX() + squareWidth, getY() + squareWidth, paint);  
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    return false;
}
```

My XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
        android:text="New Square" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I investigate further. It has nothing to do with drag and drop. I set X and Y to 30 on the creation of my square, it is only painted partilly. It seems that there is some Kind of mask on the top left Corner of the app, and the square is only displayed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple. The coordinates in the onDraw() method are belonging to the view, not to the Screen. So if I move my view via Drag and Drop to let's say (500, 500) I have to draw my rectangle in the onDraw method still at (0,0,100,100) and not at (500, 500, 600, 600) so the correct line of code would be:

canvas.drawRect(0, 0, squareWidth, squareWidth, paint);

and not

canvas.drawRect(getX(), getY(), getX() + squareWidth, getY() + squareWidth, paint);